# Running svdvis package in r?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have been trying to run the svdvis packaged in r and have not been able to.  I've gotten this warning each time I run it: Warning in install.packages : package ‘svdvis’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1).  I understand that there is probably something I can download that would help me to run this but I am not sure what and would appreciate if someone knew what that download would be!

Comment: If you look at the [CRAN page for `svdvis`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=svdvis), you'll see that the package was removed from CRAN (over 1.5 years ago).

Comment: If you need it, you might be able to install it with `devtools::install_github("ncchung/svdvis")` (since I found a repo for it here: https://github.com/ncchung/svdvis).